# Grouping elements based on ending in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
df_new = read.table(sep=",",  
    header=T,   
    text="combination,priority,boolean,value,label      
        1,1,True,1.4,1-a2  
        1,2,True,2.0,2-a3    
        1,1,True,3.2,3-b
        1,2,True,54.2,4-b  
        2,1,True,1.4,1-a2   
        2,2,True,2.0,2-a3    
        2,1,False,12.1,3-a3  
        2,2,False,44.1,4-b")
```

I want to sum the values for which I use `summarise(s=sum(value))` but I cant figure out how to group them. Normally, to do that I would use `group_by(label)` and the problem should be solved. But, now I am sorting the groups by the *ending of the label*. Meaning my groups should be `a2,a3,b` and the elements taken are based on the fact if the label ends on one of those values.

Expected output:

```
df_sol = read.table(sep=",",  
        header=T,   
        text="label,s      
            a2,2.8  
            a3,16.1    
            b,101.5")
```

Comment: yup, I have fixed it.. thanks for the notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the substring as a group by removing the digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) followed by a `-` and then do the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_new %>% 
    group_by(label = str_remove(trimws(label), '^\\d+-')) %>% 
    summarise(s = sum(value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  label     s
#* <chr> <dbl>
#1 a2      2.8
#2 a3     16.1
#3 b     102.
```

---

Or another option is with `str_replace`

```
df_new %>% 
  group_by(label = str_replace(trimws(label), ".*-([^-]+$)", "\\1")) %>% 
  summarise(s = sum(value))
```

Or we can use `trimws` in `base R`

```
aggregate(value ~ label, transform(df_new, label = trimws(label,
             whitespace = '\\d+-|\\s+')), sum)
#   label value
#1    a2   2.8
#2    a3  16.1
#3     b 101.5
```

Comment: this is practically what I needed. I was checking the regex rules to adjust it to my needs. if the label is "stream-s0_p0-s0_l" is there a way to tell him to group based on the characters after the second "-"  (in this case s0_l)?

Comment: @CroatiaHR do you have any other patterns

Comment: @CroatiaHR try wtih `str_replace` updated.  `str_replace("stream-s0_p0-s0_l", ".*-([^-]+$)", "\\1")#
[1] "s0_l"`

Comment: well to explain the label is based of three parts stream-part_a-part_b, each of them combined with a "-". and the first one is always the word "stream", the second one can be anything and the third one always begins with the letter "s" followed by a digit and ends with a "_l". Examples: stream-s0_p0-s0_l, stream-s0_aa-s3_l, stream-a2_p0-s3_l

Comment: @CroatiaHR that is working with the str_replace.  If those are vectors `str_replace(v1, ".*-([^-]+$)", "\\1")#
[1] "s0_l" "s3_l" "s3_l"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(value ~ cbind(label = gsub(".*-", "", label)), df_new, sum)
  label value
1    a2   2.8
2    a3  16.1
3     b 101.5
```

where `gsub` is applied to clean up the column `label` in `df_new`.